# In mySql I want to adjust first query's result to second query

Tags: mysql

-First Query

```
SELECT **userid** FROM user_message WHERE option = 0 AND msg IS NOT NULL
```

-Second Query

```
SELECT **userid**, useruuid FROM users WHERE userid IS NOT NULL
```

First Query's makes result table.
I want to excute second Query in First Query's result table.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to combine them with a `join`?  Something like this:

```
SELECT um.userid, um.useruuid
FROM users u JOIN
     user_message um
     ON u.userid = um.userid
WHERE um.option = 0 AND um.msg IS NOT NULL;
```